# Capture screen of Windows store App

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to capture the contents of running Windows store app? I need to capture the entire screen or a user defined rectangular area.

1. The application will provide share option
2. When the application is running and share option is selected, I want to get the screen shot periodically say 4 times in a second
3. This screen shot image will be posted to server, which will store the same

Comment: Would you like that in a Windows Store app or would a desktop app be OK? Would you like screenshots of just your app or any other app?

Comment: I want it only for Windows Store app. And the screen shot of just my App

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't capture screen programatically. See the below threads from MSDN.

[Programmatically take snap shot Windows RT.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/92e8eb38-0242-422f-baa6-67ad08a4f5b7)

[How to capture screen in Metro app?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63dd9596-bf94-440b-847a-961cbf036e7b)

Answer (score 7):

It's now possible in Windows 8.1 to capture the screen of a Store App. You need to use the **[RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** class.

You can find an example here: 
http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2013/11/05/render-the-screen-of-a-windows-store-app-to-a-bitmap-in-windows-8-1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just be careful, if you've got anything that's off-screen, even if it's visibility is set to Collapsed, the rendered image will include that area. If you supply the screen's width and height to the call to RenderAsync, this can cause the image to get squashed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in mechanism to render Windows 8 XAML UI to a bitmap in Windows 8.0. Depending on how complicated your UI is you could implement your own composition engine to render your UI to a bitmap using Direct2D or use the WinRT XAML Toolkit [WriteableBitmap.Render()](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c540adbd6952821a351d9ffa4d1d99#WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition/WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.cs) method implementation which has a limited support for doing what you ask (it doesn't render all types of controls, doesn't support RenderTransform, etc.). You could update it though to add support for the missing features.

Windows 8.1 APIs include the new ['RenderTargetBitmap'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) class that allows to render to a bitmap with its `RenderAsync` methods.